# HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout on new Android gradle

Tags: java, android, http, timeout, retrofit2

I'm using

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

and every time I try to connect to my server API it times out.

> HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

My server API is perfectly fine and I've tested it with Postman & Direct URL. The only way to fix this is to downgrade to 3.0.4 gradle plugin or connect android device to VPN. I'm from IRAN I doubt that if there is any access issues to my servers from my country. I even tried setting long timeouts for my HTTPClient but I still get the same error on every single API. However after 20-30 retries I can finally receive only 1 successful response.

I'm using Retrofit2.

I also tried setting this in my manifest but nothing changed

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Anyone else struggling with this problem? Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Mohmmad hossein for using android studio you need use VPN and nothing.

Comment: @amir133 there is no problem with building or installing the application. the problem is runtime, I can't connect to my server apis